# How safe is MVC 4 Default Database?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Im kinda new at MVC 4 and im trying to learn it. I wanted to ask how safe is mvc 4 defaul databases.

When i configure the project and enable role authorization it creates an ASPNETDB.mdf. Can i trust it and its default database in a big project?

Comment: `big project` will probably mean `big database`, which in turn would probably mean that you'd probably be better off deferring to an actual SQL server instance, rather than using the default database right out-of-the-MVC 4-box.

Comment: "database" here is pretty vague. Are you sure the security issues are in the database instead of application code to manage credentials or (for example) in the role/profile providers you will use in production? How big is a big database for credentials in your case?!

Comment: Plus, you haven't defined what "safe" means - can I lock the database MDF file in a safe with network cables?

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan what's the difference between that and a database "born" inside a SQL Server instance?! MSSQL won't treat them in a different way...

Comment: @Adriano ~ the `ASPNETDB.mdf` file is a **SQL Server Express** DB, while a DB *born* in an actual **SQL Server**, well, is expected to perform and adhere to the rigors of what `big project` is generally expected to throw at it.

Note the use of `probably` in my initial comment before biting though. I do recognize that it's not an absolute.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan It's not true. MDF files are **SQL Server** databases and that file format is used by both the full and the express editions. Nothing change in the file between these editions!!! That database is simply attached to the SQL Server instance and than it acts like any other MSSQL _born_ database. Difference are in the engine (Express edition is limited) but nothing of this is about the file format (and to upgrade, even if I can't imagine a DB of credentials which really needs it, you just have to install the full version and update the connection string).

Comment: Fore future reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx

Comment: I know that the *file* itself is just any plain SQL DB, but I was under the impression that, without tweaks on the project properties, it gets attached on an express instance *by default*. Sure, it can be attached to a SQL Server, but as is, it's attached to an express, and I was pointing out that it might be better off used in conjunction with a SQL Server instead. If this assumption is incorrect, let me know, and I'll chuck it as a *you learn something new every day* thing.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan it'll be attached to what the connection string tells (Express by default). The point is, in my opinion, WHY you do need to switch to the full version. If you use it as main database then you changed your default to it ('cause I don't think you want to keep Express on your dev machine and full on production machine). If you use it _only_ for credentials then I cannot really imagine any good reason to switch to the full version (unless you're not developing your version of SO...LOL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, by default asp.net creates MSSQL Server Compact database (localfile database). It cannot be used as database for high load project. So you need to migrate it to Normal version of MSSQL Server. To do this, you need to use Aspnet_regsql.exe tool.

Comment: Who spoke about SQL Server Express? Moreover I think it depends what _kind_ of load you're talking about...

Comment: Can you define a high load database for **credentials in ASP.NET**? Moreover MDF files are used by all versions of SQL Server.